# Detect click binding in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, binding, click

I got a component, and I want to know if there is a `(click)="..."` binding on it to change it's style (add a css class).

How can I do that ?

I tried using `@Attribute` but the `(click)` attribute is transform into an event listener by Angular (as I understand it), so I can't use it.

I also tried using `@HostListener`, but the problem is I want to know if there is a binding at the instantiation of the component, not do something on click.

Thanks all :)

**EDIT** :

Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent {

    // Thats where I want to know if there is a 'click' binding to host
}
```

Page where component is call

```
<app-my (click)="todo()" ></app-my>
```

Comment: can you add your code.

Comment: @Chellappan I added it :)